# Strange artefacts in GIF-animated image with transparency

Tags: animation, gif, adobe-animate

I try to create an animated GIF of a bee. This image is a gif with transparency. I export it in Adobe Animate CC 2018 with such settings:

[image]

but as a result: I can't use this image on web. There are to much artifacts (when my web page background has a color):

[image]

What I do wrong?

Here is my Animate project: https://www.dropbox.com/s/6s9qs8vow8bs8kn/bee.fla?dl=0 (.fla)

Comment: Have you tried exporting with only two (or four) colors? Transparency and black ONLY?

Comment: @SZCZERZOKŁY yes, it's the same

Comment: Since you say it's going on a website... Depending on the use case, you may want to export it to html5 canvas or as a sprite sheet animation. Unfortunately, I have no idea what kinda support Adobe Animate has for these. I'm pretty sure it has some sort of canvas export...

Answer (score 3):

Some possible solutions:

1. Set the transparent **Matte** color the same as the webpage
   background.

[image: matte setting]

2. Avoid antialiasing at the animation, this means pixelated border, sound hard but it is a good solution. For this, you need a good resolution file to develop your animation and simulate the borders. Some time ago, **Kenzo** use at their web page a very well done animated gif over static images with no soft borders. Here's the result:

[image: kenzo]

3. Use an **APNG** or **PNG animation file**. The con is that it's not
   supported in all browsers, some of them display a static image. Here's
   a list: https://caniuse.com/#feat=apng. With PNG and APNG files,
   you can keep the transparency or alpha channel. This image is the one
   Wikipedia uses at the [PNG Animation definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APNG).

[image: PNG]